# Cannot compile class

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out a true or false value and having difficulty compiling. Can you not print the value of a boolean method?

Errors:

```
javac ArrayManip.java
ArrayManip.java:23: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical);                      ^
ArrayManip.java:23: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical);
```

---

```
public class ArrayManip
{
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int numbers [] = {2,3,4,5,6,6,5,4,3,2};
        boolean areThey = valuesSymmetrical(numbers);

    }

    public static boolean valuesSymmetrical(int [] n)
    {
    int i = 0, y = n.length - 1;
    while (n[i] == n[j] && i < j)
    {
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    if (i < j) return true;
    else return false;
}

    System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical);
}
```

Comment: 1. You realise that `System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical);` is outside any of your methods scope? 2. If you want to invoke methods you need to add its arguments like in your case  `valuesSymmetrical(arrayOfIntegers)`. 3. What is `j` in `valuesSymmetrical` method?

Comment: try starting with properly formatting your code, you should find the issue pretty easily with proper indentation.

Comment: Not quite related to your question, but I'm fairly sure you want to change `if (i < j)` near the end to `if (i > j)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical);
```

Is outside any method.

Try like this:

```
public class ArrayManip
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int numbers [] = {2,3,4,5,6,6,5,4,3,2};
    boolean areThey = valuesSymmetrical(numbers);

    System.out.println(areThey );

  }

  public static boolean valuesSymmetrical(int [] n)
  {
    int i = 0, j = n.length - 1;  // notice here you had y and not j!
    while (n[i] == n[j] && i < j)
    {
      i++;
      j--;
    }

    if (i < j) return true;
    else return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually *call* the function, e.g.,

```
System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical(numbers));
```

Put this in your `main` method.

---

Unrelated: for your sake, and anybody else's, please format your code consistently, e.g.,

```
public class ArrayManip {

    public static boolean valuesSymmetrical(int [] n) {
        int i = 0, y = n.length - 1;
        while (n[i] == n[j] && i < j) {
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        return i < j;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numbers[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical(numbers));
    }

}
```

(This does not correct any logic errors.)

Answer (score 0):

Move your sysout up into your main method.

```
System.out.println(areThey);
```

or

```
System.out.println(valuesSymmetrical(numbers));
```